Avalonia 11 - unable to bind Text in a TextBlock (UserControl) from my ViewModel
I'm new to Avalonia and MVVM .I'm trying to create a simple GUI app, however I'm encountering a problem, when I want to bind text in my UserControl from my ViewModel I'm getting an error and can't find anything related to the error.
This is my user control:
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="using:TouchPanel.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="1024" d:DesignHeight="600"
             x:Class="TouchPanel.Views.PickUpParcelView"
             x:DataType="vm:PickUpParcelViewModel"
             Width ="1024"
             Height="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="408" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="408" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="204" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Spacing="10" Margin="50">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TEXT}"> </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock> Enter your phone number</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="TextBoxPhoneNumber"
                     IsEnabled="False" 
                     Watermark="Ex. +00 123 456 789">
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock> Enter your pick up code</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Watermark="Ex. 0000000"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" />
        <ListBox Grid.Column="2" Background="CadetBlue"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

And this is the ViewModel:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TouchPanel.DataModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm;

namespace TouchPanel.ViewModels
{
    public class PickUpParcelViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public PickUpParcel pickUpParcelDataModel;
        public string TextBoxPhoneNumber = string.Empty;
        public string TextBoxPickUpCode = string.Empty;
        public PickUpParcelViewModel()
        {
            pickUpParcelDataModel = new PickUpParcel();
            TextBoxPhoneNumber = pickUpParcelDataModel.PhoneNumber;
            TextBoxPickUpCode = pickUpParcelDataModel.PickUpCode;
        }
        public string TEXT = "ASDHASDJKHASD";
    }
}

And that's my DataModel:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace TouchPanel.DataModel
{
    public class PickUpParcel
    {
        public string PhoneNumber = "PHONENUMBERTEST";
        public string PickUpCode = "PICKUPCODETEST";
    }
}

This is the error I'm getting:
Error   AVLN:0004   Unable to resolve property or method of name 'TEXT' on type 'TouchPanel.ViewModels.PickUpParcelViewModel'.
The issue is this line:
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TEXT}"> </TextBlock>
I looked through the documentation and it seems a bit outdated, looked through various tutorials and couldn't find a good solution. I thought I bound the text correctly just like in docs, but it doesn't seem to work here. Does anyone how to solve this problem?

Instead of a public field, use a public property with at least a getter instead.
public string TEXT = "ASDHASDJKHASD";

Should become
public string TEXT {get;} = "ASDHASDJKHASD";

Keep in mind that if you need a property with a getter and a setter, you'll likely want to use INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the UI the property has updated. This is explained in more detail in the Avalonia docs: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/data-binding/inotifypropertychanged
